# Standard deviation

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, standard-deviation

The noise level of a washing machine is a aleator variable with the expected value $44$ dB and the  standard deviation $5$ dB. Admitting that aproximation is normal, find the probability that the expected value of the noise is higher to $48$ dB, in a sample with waist $10$ washing machines.

> I find that the standard deviation $ \sigma = \sqrt{ E[(X-\mu)^{2}]}$, where $\mu = E[X]$ and $ \mu = 44 dB$ and $ \sigma = 5 dB$, but I don’t know how to continue.
>   Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Central Limit Theorem: $P( \bar x > 48 ) = P\left(z > \dfrac{48 - \mu}{\dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}\right) = P\left(z >\dfrac{48-44}{\dfrac{5}{\sqrt{10}}}\right)$. Can you continue here?

Comment: We get $P(z> \sqrt{10})$, but I don't understand who is $z$.

Comment: $z$ is the relative measure of $x$ in the normal distribution.

Comment: If I understant $P(z>\sqrt{10})=1-P(z \leq \sqrt{10})=1-F(\sqrt{10})=1-0,9992=0,0008$?

Comment: Hmm, from the above I got P(z>2.52982) = .0057

Comment: Use "normalCDF" in graphing calculator where lower bound = -1000, upper cound = 2.53 and standardized mean of 0 with standard deviation 1. Then subtract 1 from this value.. OR change lower bound to 2.53 and upper bound 1000, but do not subtract 1